# Class cast exception when invoking a web service in Jboss 4.2.3 GA

Tags: jboss, jax-ws, java-6, jboss-4.2.x, jbossws

We have created a web service in Netbeans 7.1 which is running fine on glassfish 3.1.1. Now I have to move my service application to Jboss 4.2.3 GA-JDK6. There is no problem found when deploying the web service on Jboss, but however invoking the web service causes an exception: -
"**setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage class**". To overcome this problem I had added **jboss-native-saaj.jar** in the JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed. which resolved the problem and the service got invoked but failed to return the response, but it resulted in a new exception: -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPElementImpl
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.<init>(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:60)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:124)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:96)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:280)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageUnMarshallerHTTP.read(SOAPMessageUnMarshallerHTTP.java:84)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.readResponse(HTTPClientInvoker.java:518)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:307)
... 54 more
```

Also I want to tell that I'm actually invoking a webservice from within a webservice.
Please help in this, as there no documentation or solution available for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Adding the complete stacktrace of the previously occurred error:-

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.handleRemoteException(ClientImpl.java:404)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:172)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:152)
at $Proxy183.authenticateUser(Unknown Source)
at com.liaison.soi.sts.usermgmt.service.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl.authenticateUser(UserManagementServiceImpl.java:46)
at com.liaison.soi.sts.usermgmt.service.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl.authenticateUser(UserManagementServiceImpl.java:25)
at com.liaison.soi.sts.auth.AuthenticationHandler.validate(AuthenticationHandler.java:24)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.getResult(PasswordValidationCallback.java:80)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.authenticateUser(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:1166)
at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.UsernameTokenHeader.validate(UsernameTokenHeader.java:160)
at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.handleSecurityHeader(SecurityRecipient.java:341)
at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.cacheHeaders(SecurityRecipient.java:275)
at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:225)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.verifyInboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:450)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityServerTube.processRequest(SecurityServerTube.java:295)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:314)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:213)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
at javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.java:454)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:83)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:171)
at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAP11Binding.createMessage(CommonSOAP11Binding.java:59)
at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.bindRequestMessage(CommonSOAPBinding.java:158)
at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:291)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
```

Comment: You get this exception because SAAJ implementation comes with JDK itself and in your case this implementation has overridden the one from JBoss. Usually SOAP factory is defined by library itself, but in your case it did not work. I would suggest to come back to 1st exception, and try to solve the problem from there. If you show more complete stack trace for `setProperty` problem perhaps I'll get some ideas.

Comment: Hi @dma_k, thanks for your quick response. I have added the complete stack trace in the question itself above as requested. Also want to tell you that I have built the services using Sun's Metro Framework and I'm want to call a webservice from another service.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in following.

The implementation `SOAPMessageImpl` was packaged in `jboss-native-saaj.jar` only till JBoss 3.2.2.GA (check [here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/jboss/ws/native/jbossws-native-saaj/)). Latest JBoss has this class in `jbossws-native-core.jar`. So you create a class conflict when you put `jboss-native-saaj.jar` into `server/libs` (or package with your application). So the **solution** will be: just remove `jboss-native-saaj.jar`, as `jbossws-native-core.jar` is (I believe) already there.

To make sure check `META-INF` for `jboss-native-saaj.jar`: was it packaged for JBoss 4.2.3? what is that date of packaging? This will take you to right decision.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily googled.

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-1439 and https://community.jboss.org/message/618306.

It's a well-known issue under Java 6 caused by obsolete jax-ws jars bundled within.

You'll have to play with moving some jars to endorsed dir as noted in above issue.

An alternative solution is to [upgrade](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-Installation) to [JBossWS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/downloads)-3.1.1 (the last one supporting JBoss AS 4.2.3.GA).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue in JBoss 5.1.2 is resolved with the addition of

```
jboss-as/lib/endorsed/jbossws-native-factories-3.1.2.SP11.jar
```